# the files on Kennedy and Marilyn

Tags: meaning, conjunctions, ambiguity

a. They are going to publish the CIA files on Kennedy and Marilyn Monroe.

Can't that sentence have two meanings:

1. They are going to publish the CIA files on Kennedy and those on Marilyn Monroe.
2. They are going to publish the CIA files on Kennedy and Marilyn Monroe's relationship.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

The quick answer is yes. The sentence is ambiguous. Without further context it is impossible to say which interpretation is meant.